# Is it possible to ignore pre-launch report errors in Google Play?

Tags: android, automated-tests, google-play, publish

I am trying to post and application to open test in google play and getting some errors I can't reproduce. Can I ignore these errors or it is a blocking situation for proceeding with open test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre-launch report provide a more comprehensive review of your app that include issues related with Stability, Compatibility, Performance, Accessibility and Security.

[image]

there is no button to ignore the issues because is just a report created from your apk. You can ignore the issues and publish your app but this will lead to a bad behaviour and low KPI of your app and will cause that the users will uninstall it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand drawbacks... How to ignore it? I see no buttons for this?

Comment: Nop, there is no button to ignore the issues because is just a report created from your apk

Comment: @Jorgesys, what do you mean "created from your APK". Do you mean that the APK contains this information after the build, or do you mean that some person somewhere is actually testing the apk on their device? I am having trouble getting rid of a few errors that I never have provoked  on many devices used to test the app. Hence my question.

Comment: @carl when you upload your .apks some processes automatically check the operation of the application even on several devices, wich is the error could you show the stack trace?

Comment: The report is not perfect, and has bugs of its own, incorrectly claiming an app has crashes.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919198/java-lang-runtimeexception-android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-no-such-tab).

Comment: Does that mean; I can still ignore the Error or Warning and Publish the App ?

Comment: @RiteshAryal yes, you can publish your app, but it is preferable to solve the indicated problems.